# Meteor Facebook ask for additional permissions

Tags: meteor

I am using accounts-ui and accounts-facebook but can't figure out how to ask for permission to post on a users behalf.  I don't see where it is currently asking for email, public profile, and friends list permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
     facebook: ['publish_stream'],
  }
});
```

See http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_ui_config for how to request other permissions.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/ for facebook permissions reference.

Comment: And if i dont have accounts.ui package?